# php foreach loop with 2 variables in json_decode

Tags: php, json, foreach

In a foreach loop i am trying to make a link with data from two variables. Like this:

```
$baseAttachementUrl = str_replace($rowAttachTags, $rowAttachVals, $getAttachmentURL);

foreach ($attachments as $attachment){ 
$rowAttachTags = array('{{ROWID}}', '{{SHEETID}}','{{ATTACHMENTID}}');
$rowAttachVals = array($addRowsObj->result[0]->id, $theSheet->id, $attachment->id);
$getAttachmentURL = $baseAttachementUrl; 
$getNEWAttachmentURL = str_replace($rowAttachTags, $rowAttachVals, $getAttachmentURL);

$curlSession = curl_init($getNEWAttachmentURL);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
getAttachmentResponse = curl_exec($curlSession);

$getFileObj = array(json_decode($getAttachmentResponse, true));

foreach ($getFileObj as $fileObj){
echo "<a href='". $fileObj['url']."'>". $fileObj['name']."</br></a>";       
}
}
```

The first row in the table works. 2 files comes out with the right url. but in all subsequent rows the last file from the first row comes out.

Comment: Please add an example of the JSON that is returned by the curl request. Edit your question rather than adding it as a comment!

Comment: Also does not this `foreach ($attachments as $attachments){ ` want to be using `foreach ($getFileObj as $attachments){ `

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: Add a `print_r($getFileObj);` after the `json_decode()` so you can see what is being returned. Then paste a few records from what you get so we can see what you are trying to process.

Comment: Your main issue is here `$attachments as $attachments`. You should remove the 's' from the last `$attachments` and use `$attachment` (no 's' at the end) in your `echo` commando

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems here that you are not being too specific about. However I will try my best to respond.

First of all, we dont know how the results of `$attachments` or `$getFileObj` look like. We are assuming that the part of your question that says "returns stdClas..." is a portion of the results of `$getFileObj`.

Another problem is that we dont know where you're getting `$getAttachmentURL` from.. Is this a variable statically set, or is it a variable that comes as a result of `$attachments`?

Taking those problems into consideration I believe what you're trying to do is to first get the all the attachments and store them into `$attachments`. Then, you want to get each attachment url from you intial result and iterate through each to get your fileURL. I would do the following:

```
<?php

curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$getAttachmentsResponse = curl_exec($curlSession);
// Assign response to variable
$attachments = json_decode($getAttachmentsResponse);


foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    $getAttachmentURL = $attachment->attachment_URL;
    $curlSession = curl_init($getAttachmentURL);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $getAttachmentResponse = curl_exec($curlSession);
    // Assign response to variable 
    $getFileObj = json_decode($getAttachmentResponse);
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='" . $getFileObj->url . "'>" . $attachment->name . "</br></a>";
    echo "</td>";
}
```

Comment: You are right in what i am trying to do, but your example do not work. I tried somthing new and it is almost there. Check my update in the top. 
In the attachment array alle the attachments comes out with id and name. In getfileobj the files id, name, creater and url comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Try....

```
// ... curl setup
$attach = json_decode($getAttachmentsResponse);
// ... curl setup two
$file = json_decode($getAttachmentResponse);
$joinedattachment[ 'attach' ] = $attachone;
$joinedattachment[ 'file' ]   = $file;
$attachments[] = $joinedattachment;

$iCountAttachments = count( $attachments );
echo "<td>";      
for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountAttachments; ++$i )
{
    echo "<a href='". $attachments[ $i ][ 'file' ]."'>". $attachments[ $i ][ 'attach' ] ."</br></a>";
}
echo "</td>";
```